# display highest/lowest and the avg of inputed marks - C programming

Tags: c, loops, if-statement

I'm writing a c program for my intro class and I'm stuck on the if/else statements. we have to output the highest,lowest grade entered as well as the avg for those. Marks entered must be between 0-100. this is my code so far, i can't seem to figure it out, thanks for any advice! :

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
{

  int numberofMarks;
  int i;
  int x;
  int y;

  int numofPasses=1;
  int numofFails=1;
  float sumpassedMarks =0;
  float sumfailedMarks=0;
  float markEntered=0;
  float highestMark=0;
  float lowestMark=0;
  float totalMark=0;
  float avgofMarks=0;
  float avgpassedMarks=0;
  float avgfailedMarks=0;



        printf ("       ---=== IPC mark Analyser ===---\n");
        printf ("Please enter the number of marks(between 3 and 40): ");
         scanf ("%d", &numberofMarks);


//asks user for number of marks, only takes 3-40, otherwise outputs error msg
        for (i=1 ; (numberofMarks < 3)||(numberofMarks > 40) ; i++) {
          printf ("Invalid number, enter a number between 3 and 40 inclusive: ");
          scanf ("%d", &numberofMarks);
        }

//for loop recieves the mark
        for (x=1 ;(x <= numberofMarks) ; x++) {
          printf ("%d> ", x);
          scanf ("%f", &markEntered);


//contd loop..loop makes sure mark entered is between 1-100
        for (y=1; (markEntered <0)||(markEntered>100); y++)
        {
            printf ("Error, Enter values between 0 and 100 incluisve.\n");
            printf ("%d> ", x);
             scanf ("%f", &markEntered);


            if (markEntered >= 50) {
              numofPasses=numofPasses+1;
           }

            if else (markEntered <= 49) {
              numofFails = numofFails+1;
           }

            if else (markEntered > highestMark) {
              highestMark = markEntered;
           }

            else (markEntered < lowestMark) {
              lowestMark = markEntered;
           }

        }
//adds the mark entered to all the marks entered for a overall sum
        totalMark = totalMark + markEntered;
        }

        avgofMarks = (float)totalMark / numberofMarks;
        avgpassedMarks = (float)sumpassedMarks / numberofMarks;
        avgfailedMarks = (float)sumfailedMarks / numberofMarks;


        printf ("Total of %d students passed with an average of %.1f.\n", numofPasses,avgpassedMarks);
        printf ("Total of %d students failed with an average of %.1f.\n", numofFails, avgfailedMarks);
        printf ("Highest mark in the group: %.1f\n", highestMark);
        printf ("lowest mark in the group: %.1f\n", lowestMark);
        printf ("The average of all marks in this group is %.1f.\n", avgofMarks);
        printf ("Program Ended.\n");

return 0;

}
```

[The work](https://github.com/Seneca-144100/IPC-WS3/blob/master/Workshop3.pdf) asks,

> In the loop in which marks are being entered, after each entry examine the value of the mark entered:
>
> - If it is a pass, add one to the number of passes and add the value of the mark to the sum of passed marks.
> - If it is a fail, add one to the number of fails and add the value of the mark to the sum of failed marks.
> - If the value is higher than the highest mark, set highest mark to the value read.
> - If the value is lower than the lowest mark, set the lowest mark to
>   the value read. After all the marks are entered and examined, divide
>   the sums by the corresponding number of marks to get the average and
>   print the results.

[This is my output vs the sample output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zhnhe.png).

Comment: This is not a homework service. Try to ask a more specific question where you struggle at the moment (and what you've tried so far)

Comment: Why are the numbers of passes and fails 1 and not 0 before you've read anything?  That is a worrying pair of initializations.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is a mess; let's try to get some things straight here:

- If you're not gonna use `i` in the body of a for loop, no reason to initialize and increment it. Better to use a while.
- When you post a question, clear all not-strictly-necessary code from the answer, so that it's easier to help
- Instead of making 15 variables, consider using an array or, if you're not gonna use the values later in the program, print  the result directly.

Ex.

`int a = 10, b = 15;` If you wanna print the sum, no reason to save it in a new `int sum`, just printf("%d", a + b);

- Do not request the number of votes outside of a loop, and then loop to verify the value (your first for loop). Consider a DO..WHILE loop instead.

Ex.

```
do{

 scanf("%d", &n);

} while(n <= 0);

//Scan integer and save into n, until you get a positive value
```

- Avoid nesting for loops for no reason, use more `if() .. else if()` .. if necessary.
- It's not the best of practise, but you can also use the `continue` and `break` keywords to continue or stop the loops respectively.
- Do not use "else" randomly. If you have more conditions to check, leave the if without else. You wanna use else after an if condition if  (when the first condition comes back true) you **don't want** to check the next condition (**they will be skipped !**)

Comment: Note that you should check the return value from `scanf()` before using the value that was (or maybe wasn't) read.  And `while` loops are better than `do … while` loops in general.